# C# Generic types - There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'IMyBaseInterface'

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following structure of my code.

```
public interface IMyBaseInterface
{
}


public interface IMySubInterface : IMyBaseInterface
{
}



public abstract class BaseClass<T> 
    where T : IMyBaseInterface, new()

{

}

public class SubBaseClass<T> :
  BaseClass<T> where T : IMySubInterface , new()
{

}
```

However I am getting this error.

> CS0314    The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'BaseClass<T>'. There is no boxing
>   conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to
>   'IMyBaseInterface'

I can easily add the other constraint like this and the error is fixed.

```
public class SubBaseClass<T> : BaseClass<T> 
    where T : IMySubInterface, IMyBaseInterface, new()
{

}
```

But isn't it implicitly implied that If I say that the template type will be/inherit/implement (the ':' symbol) the `IMySubInterface` it will also implement `IMyBaseInterface`?

EDIT: I realised that I had just missed the `IMySubInterface : IMyBaseInterface` part (my interface wasn't implementing the other interface)

Comment: It seems compiled just fine for me: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAjAO2AUwE4DMCGBjNBASQFkBPAIRwGc0jVNcCBYAKAG82BfN31+JA2z5CpMgGUArgCN66YQQQhi5KrTmMRbTqx6s+bATmnVgGfMAQwATAjVoAwhBrUAPABUAfAjYI/CAHcAC0xCdyUVSho6ISY0ABoEZDQAgAoASj4dbj4BGwQpaXsnFw9vEF87aJLqNy9AkIwwiLFCjQVCROS0zI4+LiA